# union issue for getting total count

Tags: mysql

How can we count the total records of UNION of 2 select statement through query in MySql?

```
(select name, phone from table1) UNION (select name, phone from table2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use derived tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  (select name, phone from table1) 
  UNION 
  (select name, phone from table2)
  ) AS combined_table
```

UPD: here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94df3/1)

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want? Your question is to unclear to me.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRecordCount
FROM
     (select name, phone from table1
          UNION 
     select name, phone from table2) as UnionTable
```

Comment: it is giving "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @PoonamBhatt are you sure? The unioned table has already an `ALIAS` named `UnionTable`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    (select name, phone from table1) UNION (select name, phone from table2)  
)
```

Comment: it is giving "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"